# Maximum Sum of XOR operation on a selected element with array elements with an optimize approach

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Problem: Choose an element from the array to maximize the sum after XOR all elements in the array.

Input for problem statement:
N=3
A=[15,11,8]

Output:
11

Approach:
(15^15)+(15^11)+(15^8)=11

My Code for brute force approach:

```
def compute(N,A):
    ans=0
    for i in A:
      xor_sum=0
      for j in A:
        xor_sum+=(i^j)
      if xor_sum>ans:
          ans=xor_sum
    return ans
```

Above approach giving the correct answer but wanted to optimize the approach to solve it in O(n) time complexity. Please help me to get this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have integers with a fixed (constant) number of `c` bites then it should be possible because O(c) = O(1). For simplicity reasons I assume unsigned integers and n to be odd. If n is even then we sometimes have to check both paths in the tree (see solution below). You can adapt the algorithm to cover even n and negative numbers.

1. find `max` in array with length `n` O(n)
2. if `max == 0` return 0 (just 0s in array)
3. find the position `p` of the most significant bit of `max` O(c) = O(1)

   ```
    p = -1
    while (max != 0)
        p++
        max /= 2
   ```

   so `1 << p` gives a mask for the highest set bit
4. build a tree where the leaves are the numbers and every level stands for a position of a bit, if there is an edge to the left from the root then there is a number that has bit `p` set and if there is an edge to the right there is a number that has bit `p` not set, for the next level we have an edge to the left if there is a number with bit `p - 1` set and an edge to the right if bit `p - 1` is not set and so on, this can be done in O(cn) = O(n)
5. go through the array and count how many times a bit at position i (i from 0 to p) is set => `sum` array O(cn) = O(n)
6. assign the root of the tree to node `x`
7. now for each `i` from `p` to 0 do the following:

   1. if `x` has only one edge => `x` becomes its only child node
   2. else if `sum[i]` > `n / 2` => `x` becomes its right child node
   3. else `x` becomes its left child node

   in this step we choose the best path through the tree that gives us the most ones when xoring O(cn) = O(n)
8. xor all the elements in the array with the value of `x` and sum them up to get the result, actually you could have built the result already in the step before by adding `sum[i] * (1 << i)` to the result if going left and `(n - sum[i]) * (1 << i)` if going right O(n)

All the sequential steps are O(n) and therefore overall the algorithm is also O(n).